# Create Jenkins jobs for github projects programmatically

Tags: java, github, jenkins

How to create Jenkins jobs for github projects programmatically in Java and what we need to configure in `config.xml`

Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can build a job in Jenkins itself to create additional jobs using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin.

You can add build steps to create additional jobs written in [groovy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29) and then regenerate them as you require

This works with any plugin you have, either directly or by passing in configuration blocks of XML like structures

You can also create jobs without using Jenkins - example from https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/User-Power-Moves (you will need to pull the source from github and build it)

> Add some job dsl content to a file, say job.dsl
>
> Run the gradle
>   command: ./gradlew run -Pargs=job.dsl
>
> Note: the run task loads the file relative to the job-dsl-core
>   directory, so I always just put my test files in there. Note2: if your
>   dsl code contains a job named "myJob", the run task will generate
>   myJob.xml.

---

EDIT
there is a specific github example on the main page to build all branches in a project

```
def project = 'quidryan/aws-sdk-test'
def branchApi = new URL("https://api.github.com/repos/${project}/branches")
def branches = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(branchApi.newReader())
branches.each {
    def branchName = it.name
    job {
        name "${project}-${branchName}".replaceAll('/','-')
        scm {
            git("git://github.com/${project}.git", branchName)
        }
        steps {
            maven("test -Dproject.name=${project}/${branchName}")
        }
    }
}
```